# Woocommerce - single product - show different content for different products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to show different content on single product page for different categories.

Sample code

```
<?php if(in_category('62')){ ?>Text for category 62<?php }?>
<?php if(in_category('21')){ ?>Text for category 21<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the new template and name it: taxonomy-product_cat-Your_category_product_slug.php

Path: /wp-content/your-theme/woocommerce/taxonomy-product_cat-Your_category_product_slug.php

Another way to do this:

```
$cat1 = 62;
$cat2 = 21;

$terms = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
if (!empty($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $t) {
        if ($t->term_id == $cat1) {
            woocommerce_get_template_part('single-product-product1');
        } else if ($t->term_id == $cat2) {
            woocommerce_get_template_part('single-product-product2');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Working solltuion on single product page is:

<?php
global $post;
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) $categories[] = $term->slug;

if ( has_term( 'In audio', 'product_cat' ) ) { ?>

       echo 'In audio';

} elseif ( has_term( 'elektro', 'product_cat' ) ) {

       echo 'In elektro';

} else {
       echo 'some blabla';
}?>